# Yobit c#, jsonconvert.deserialize

Tags: c#, json.net, json-deserialization

From https://yobit.net/api/3/depth/btc_usd?limit=5 i have

```
    string response = { "btc_usd":{ "asks":[[6657,0.06689384],[6680.47685546,0.001],[6680.47690546,0.00526334],[6697,0.05],[6698,0.05]],"bids":[[6656,0.02371773],[6640.00000001,0.0297727],[6640,0.34752146],[6637.46352566,0.0011574],[6634,0.00424518]]}}
```

I want to deserialize this.
I created some classes

```
public class Orderbook
{
    [JsonProperty("asks")]
    public List<BidAsk> asks { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("bids")]
    public List<BidAsk> bids { get; set; }
}   


public class BidAsk
{
    public decimal price { get; set; }
    public decimal volume { get; set; }
}

var jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Orderbook>(response);
```

After this operation i got: 
jsonResponse.asks = null
jsonResponse.bids = null

What I've done wrong in deserialization?

Comment: I would advise just pasting your json into http://json2csharp.com/ and click generate and it will give you the classes you need for deserialization.

Answer (score 2):

There's an extra level for the currency. Try something like:

```
public class Orderbook
{
    [JsonProperty("btc_usd")]
    public Currency BTCToUSD{ get; set; }
}  

public class Currency
{
    [JsonProperty("asks")]
    public double[][] asks { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("bids")]
    public double[][] bids { get; set; }
}

var jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Orderbook>(response);
```

Note I've changed the bid/asks to arrays of arrays of doubles as that's how they are in your example.

You might want to look into `decimal` too, not sure how Json.NET handles it, but when dealing with finance you probably want to be cautious with floating precision.

Comment: Thanks, it helped! But if I have another pair, for example "eth_usd"? How recognize it in jsonconverter?

Answer (score 0):

How deserialize these responses if I don't know, which pair i got?
For example, two different requests:

1)https://yobit.net/api/3/depth/btc_usd?limit=5

2)https://yobit.net/api/3/depth/eth_usd?limit=5

Should I create a new JsonProperty for another pair "eth_usd"?

```
[JsonProperty("eth_usd")]
public Currency ETHToUSD{ get; set; }
```

In this case in each request all other attributes of class will be null. 
I want to get something like this:

```
   var Asks = jsonresponse.pair_name.asks
```